# Force file owner on mac share to match windows AD of user writing file?

Tags: macos, sharing, active-directory

We have several Ventura Macs bound to our Active Directory servers. The Macs have SMB shares on them that are accessible to Windows machines on the network. The Mac users log in using the same AD credentials as they do on the Windows machines. Permissions are all fine on the Mac shares and both the Macs and the Windows machine scan read and write files and folders to the Mac shares.

However, when a Mac user (using AD Credentials and login) or a Windows user (using AD Credentials and login) write to the Mac Shares, the files show no ownership from the Windows file properties dialog. This makes identifying who wrote the files/folders difficult.

I don't wish to change the file ownership after they are written--I'd like the files & folders to show the owner/user that wrote them. Is there something in the MacOS that must be altered to use the file ownership of the AD User writing the files?